# How to use webpack babel-loader and es6 with worker-loader?

Tags: ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs, web-worker

I'm trying to use `worker-loader` with `babel` for es6 import support in web worker code.

I have the following setup in my `webpack.config.js`

```
   {
     test: /\.worker\.js$/,
     loader: "worker!babel",
     presets: ['es2015']
   }
```

This correctly produces a sepearte bundle file for the worker with a hash name like `d46f60b8e184bf8b1cb8.worker.js`

However this file is not run through the Babel transforms and converted to es5. So it contains raw es6 import statmenets and syntax that is failing in a browser. Looks like:

```
/* 0 */
/***/ function(module, exports) {

    import _ from 'lodash';

    var o = {foo: 'foo'};

    _.has(o, 'foo'); // true

    setInterval(() => {
       postMessage({tick: Date.now()});
    }, 1000);


/***/ }
/******/ ]);
```

I have tried switching the order of the loaders like:

```
   {
     test: /\.worker\.js$/,
     loader: "babel!worker",
     presets: ['es2015']
   }
```

and also tried moving it to `preLoaders` and `postLoaders` with no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and had success by using the query string parameter mentioned under options [here](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader):

So:

```
{
    test: /\.worker\.js$/,
    loader: "worker!babel?presets[]=es2015"
}
```